# How can i connect Luis to Node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

This is my first time working with `node.js` and i have to connect it to Luis, what i tried to do so far is a simple example available in the docs where the bot repeats what the user says and it gave an error as i seemingly am linking `LUIS` to `node.js` badly although I referred to the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-nodejs-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample
precisely

```
// app.js - register LUIS endpoint API
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(process.env.LUIS_MODEL_URL);
bot.recognizer(recognizer)
```

;

My code

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var http = require('http');
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(MY_PATH_TO_LUIS_HTTP);
bot.recognizer(recognizer);
// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: MY_ID,
    appPassword:MY_PASS
});

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

// Receive messages from the user and respond by echoing each message back (prefixed with 'You said:')
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
});
```

So again what i'm trying to do is connect the Luis successfully to node.js then run the output in the cmd and test it in the `bot framework channel emulator`.
Kindly note that i have tested the code without adding

```
var http = require('http');
    var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(MY_PATH_TO_LUIS_HTTP);
    bot.recognizer(recognizer);
```

at first and it worked fine and i know that what i set in `LuiS` is different than what this `node.js` should do(repeat my words) but I'm just still getting a feel of how to link things.

**Edit :** I got this error [image: Error]

so i went to the command line and used this command `npm install --save recognizer` then imported to my code above by adding `var recognizer = require ('recognizer');`
still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in the right direction. The main issue is that you are doing 
`bot.recognizer` before `bot` is declared :) (you are doing it at the bottom of the code)

Also, I believe that what it's missing is defining the intents methods that will handle the responses from LUIS.

You might want to check the following resources:

- [Recognize intents and entities with LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis)
- The [intelligence-LUIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS) Node.js sample

Comment: Hey and thanks for your reply, i have edited my question and added the error message and what i've also tried.

Comment: You don't need to do npm install --save recognizer at all. You need to do npm install --save botbuilder instead.

Comment: oh ok that was done in a previous step so all good, can you suggest a more concise and clear approach on what i should do differently or adjust to get my platform working as intended

Comment: I see and i have checked these 2 links before, but as a started in node.js and chatbots they're too complex for my liking and understanding, for example let's say my Luis chat bot has an intent calendar add and entities Calendar.Location and Calendar.Subject, what should i change in the code i shared with you above to get an output "your calendar has been set to a business meeting in sacramento california" assuming the user have said add a business meeting in sacramento california

Comment: Seems to be another question, mark this as answered and create new one please

Comment: kindly check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671071/how-can-i-properly-get-my-luis-chatbot-working