# How can I properly get my Luis chatbot working?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have to connect Luis to node.js and create my first chatbot that, as a first stage should handle simple requests.

I have checked the following links :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS

but getting started has proven to be difficult, what I've done as a first stage is:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var http = require('http');
var recognizer = require ('recognizer');


// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: MY_APP_ID,
    appPassword:MY_PASSWORD
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session,args) {
}
});
    var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LUIS_ENDPOINT_URL);
    bot.recognizer(recognizer);
```

and not sure how to move forward from here.

What I have in a Luis `intent` is: `calendar.add`
what I have as `entities` is: `calendar.location` and `calendar.subject`

what I want the user to say in the bot framework channel emulator:

```
add a business meeting schedule in Paris.
```

What the bot should say: `Understood the location is Paris and subject is business meeting.`

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/Microsoft/LUIS-Samples/tree/master/bot-integration-samples/hotel-finder/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the utterance `add a business meeting schedule in Paris.` doesn't match the `Calendar.Add` intent. So you can try to manually add this utterance in the intent in your LUIS application.

1. Go to your LUIS application, click `Intents` list, click `Calendar.Add` into the edit page.
2. Type the utterance `add a business meeting schedule in Paris.` in the box, type enter add the utterance into the list. [image]
3. Click the `business` and `meeting` letters into a big square brackets, select `Calendar.Subject` in dropdown list, the same click `Paris` and select `Calendar.Location`. Finishing the actions, it should looks like:
   [image]
4. Click `Save` to save the edition. Then Train and publish your LUIS application.

Then your bot should match the utterance.

Comment: It's more of a node.js code issue kindly refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678543/which-branches-of-stack-is-good-if-want-to-check-my-entire-code